# real time project with ORM

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, nosql

Often heard that the performance of any ORM can not achieve the performance of a direct connection via ADO.Net, is this true?
I'm riding an application that is in real time and I am in dilemma to assemble the initial architecture, or do I use an ORM layer data with ADO.Net? If you use an ORM which would have more performance?

A real-time application would only be produced with NoSQL or there is a case to be made ​​with SQL?

I do not know if that would be my biggest problem for such an application, but I think it would be one of the most important, what other problems exist for an application in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Often heard that the performance of any ORM can not achieve the
>   performance of a direct connection via ADO.Net, is this true?

No, this site [uses ORM](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and it is usually pretty fast.

> I'm riding an application that is in real time

There is no standard definition of real time. Windows OS (apart from some mobile editions) is not a real-time OS. You need to have better definition for real-time.

> A real-time application would only be produced with NoSQL or there is a case to be made ​​with SQL?

It depends. It can use SQL, it can use NoSql, it can use no database at all, it can be written in Assembly.

> I do not know if that would be my biggest problem for such an application ...

It would be to define your requirements first. No clear requirements means you can ask many more questions here and don't get closer to your aim.

Comment: Oleksii when I speak in a real-time application I mean an application with great performance and fast as the current social network

Comment: It's still a vague definition. How great? How fast? If you put this on a scale, define acceptable criteria, mean time to failure, average response time, these will give a better material to understand a *realtime* term in your domain. I believe your biggest problem is in the vague requirements. No clear requirements = dead project with no exceptions. Matter of time.

Comment: The part of real-time applications has been the lack of my knowledge, I sought information and really would not be viable, I think I expressed wrong with my question, what I really wanted to ask would be: focusing on performance is there any difference in using ORM or ADO.Net? Even with large data?